# Get unique values from a dataset using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `TypeDataSet` with rows and multiple columns.

```
Col1     
14    
14    
12
```

I want to write a LINQ query which would return all the unique values from `Col1`.

Comment: Can you please provide some arrangement and code?

Comment: DataSet is a collection of DataTable. So how your DataSet Contains columns? Could you please be more specific about your question?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Distinct()`

```
var uniqueValues =  TypeDataSet.Select(c => c.Col1).Distinct();
```